# Some fonts not installed on Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, windows-10, font

When I install the `.ttf` file for the font `Bahnschrift` on Windows 10 all fonts in the font file become available. Installing the same font file on Windows Server 2012 R2 only 1 font becomes available.

These font versions are in the Windows 10 `Font` directory:
[image]

This is in the Windows Server 2012 R2 `Font` directory [not displayed fields are empty]:
[image]

**My questions:**

What am I doing wrong, how can all of the font versions become available on Windows Server 2012 R2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked this question on [GitHub](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/typography-issues/issues/389) and the answer is:

> Bahnschrift is a variable font. It was introduced as a new addition to
>   the Windows font family (Windows 10 version 1709 release on October
>   17, 2017). Prior version of Windows do not support variable fonts.
>   This is why you are seeing only regular weight available on Windows
>   Server 2012 R2. This font should not be available on Windows Server
>   2012 R2